# VBA: Input SUM formula for background filled cells ONLY

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA and I am attempting to write a piece of code that will insert a sum formula into the blue cells and will sum down until the next blue cell (see attached). The reason I need this to be done is because this will be a template for users who will be inserting a text file into this spread sheet so I want it to format the cells and add formulas so if they decide to add a new row it will recalculate the total automatically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Let me know if you need more detail!

[image: F1]

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not real sure how the rest of your data looks past the screenshot, but something like this should work. I tried to comment as thoroughly as possible to help explain how it was done so you can learn more about how VBA works.

```
Sub SumBetweenBlues()

'declare your variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, y As Long, endRow As Long, startSum As Long, endSum As Long, xBlue as Long
Dim colL As String

'set the worksheet to work with (this can be changed if necessary)
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'set the color of blue to check for
xBlue = RGB(201, 234, 236)

'column where the sums will be put (C)
Const sumCol As Integer = 3

'first row
Const startRow As Integer = 2

'turns the column number into a letter for the formula
colL = colLetter(sumCol)

'determines the last used row and goes a bit past it since blues may/may not be blank themselves
endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sumCol).End(xlUp).Row + 50

'loop through all the cells in the sum column
For x = startRow To endRow

    'checks if the cell is blue
    If ws.Cells(x, sumCol).Interior.Color = xBlue Then

        'set the start of the sum range to the cell after the blue cell
        startSum = x + 1

        'find the end of the sum range
        For y = startSum + 1 To endRow

            'checks if the cell is also blue
            If ws.Cells(y, sumCol).Interior.Color = xBlue Then

                'sets the end of the sum range to the cell before the blue cell
                endSum = y - 1
                Exit For

            End If
        Next y

        'so long as an endsum area was found, set the formula in the blue cell
        If endSum <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(x, sumCol).Formula = "=SUM(" & colL & startSum & ":" & colL & endSum & ")"
        End If

        'skip all the non-blue cells inbetween
        x = y - 1

        'reset the start/end of the sum area
        startSum = 0
        endSum = 0

    End If

Next x

End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function colLetter(intCol As Integer) As String
'this function turns column numbers into letters
Dim vArr: vArr = Split(Cells(1, intCol).Address(True, False), "$"): colLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

I would advise checking out the Help Center (https://stackoverflow.com/help) and reading some of the topics there, as posting a question like this without showing what you've tried will typically get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks J. Fox! I'll give this a try. I was going to post what I had but A) It wasn't much and B) I had no clue how to really find the colored cells to begin with =(. I'll let you know what I come back with!

Comment: Hi JFox I'm getting 'Constant expression required' For the RGB for some reason. Do I need to set that as a Const as well?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I would just change `Const xBlue As Long = RGB(201, 234, 236)` to `Dim xBlue as Long` on one line and `xBlue = RGB(201, 234, 236)` on the next (I changed the answer above to reflect this change).

Comment: You sir, are amazing. It worked!! Thank you!!